# Is it possible set ip in docker container from same net as host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have twenty five containers in my docker-compose.yml file. 
And I have external server with database PostgreSQL that run on host (not in docker container). 
All containers can send request to database.
I would like to get IP addresses of container that send request to database.
When I try get info from DB, I can see only IP of host with docker containers.

One of the ideas it is add server lan interface to custom docker bridge net. Then I will can setup my lan network IP-addresses in each container.

Unfortunately, I can't run Postgres also in docker and configure docker-swarm or kubernetes. One of customer requirement it is run Postgres locally in a separate host.

Comment: can you grep the tcp connections to the server port? if the server doesn't provide a profiler or something that can inspect the connections

Comment: You can get the IP of a Docker container via `docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID` as noted in the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#examples)

Comment: use docker run or compose with --net=host

Comment: Short answer, with the default bridge or overlay networks: no.